# Linphone reregistering to Sip server using Android

Tags: android, linphone, sip-server

I am creating an Android application which uses Linphone to enable Voip calls.

When the connection is lost, I'm attempting to reconnect to the Sip server like this:

```
@Override
public void reregister()
{
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            linphoneCore.getDefaultProxyConfig().edit();
            linphoneCore.getDefaultProxyConfig().enableRegister(true);
            linphoneCore.getDefaultProxyConfig().done();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that many times when using it, the `onRegisterFailed`, `onRegisterSucceeded` and even `onRegisterProcessing` are not getting called, even though the internet connection is fine.

Is the way I'm trying to reregister correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to attempt a reconnection with the same register informations, you can used:

> linphone_core_refresh_registers()

So in your case in Java:

> linphoneCore.refreshRegisters()

Comment: Do you know if the way I'm doing it now is indeed wrong?

Comment: I think it's not refreshing your register so i think it's wrong.